# Can data tapes be recorded/played on a standard cassette recorder?

Tags: data-transfer, tape

I just bought a [TRS-80 PC-1](http://oldcomputers.net/trs80pc1.html) pocket computer with a tape deck interface.

The tape deck has 2 standard 1/4" Mono jacks (input [speaker] and output [mic]) and 1 smaller one labeled "Remote".

None of the tape recorders that I have have a 'remote' input, can I still record/playback data tapes on them, or do I need to buy a specialized recorder?

Comment: how is this off topic?

Comment: Haven't a clue, other than the topic doesn't interest some people.  It's clearly about computer hardware.

Comment: [meta](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3702/why-was-this-question-356778-closed/) question about this close

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm about 95% sure that the old "Trash 80" was designed to work with an ordinary audio cassette recorder.  But likely it needs to be able to control the motor to stop/start between data blocks.

One of your tape recorders may have a "remote" switch contact incorporated into the microphone jack, such that a simple adapter cable would make everything work.

(If the microphone that came with the recorder has a switch on it, and the plug is a 3- wire plug (tip, ring, and sleeve) then it should be adaptable.)

Comment: So you mean to splice the 'remote' tip to the 'mic' ring?

Comment: Basically.  Ideally one would do a little buzzing out with an ohmmeter first, but I'd say that you'd have 75-90% chance that "remote" tip to "mic" ring would work.